# Auto-snapshot or suspend on host power-off or log-off

Tags: windows, windows-10, vmware, vmware-workstation

My main development environment is an Ubuntu VM guest running on a beefy Windows 10 Pro host (64GB ram, 16 core i9, 1TB SSD, etc). This is the best dev setup I have had so far, with one exception: Windows Update reboots my machine at regular intervals. This means I lose the state of whatever I was doing in the VM, which sucks, in case I left work in the middle of a debugging session.

How can I configure VMWare to automatically take a snapshot when VMWare is instructed to close by the (host) operating system?

I see there are various scripts (seems like Powershell?) floating around in the VMWare forums, so I could probably hack something together, if I was presented with an API or a VMWare Powershell SDK, but it would of course be much smoother if this functionality was already built-in. The only settings I found deal with what VMWare does with the snapshot when the guest powers down (Options -> Snapshot), not what to do when the host powers down.

I am thinking that hooking a monitor into the System part of the Windows Event Log would do the trick, but it sounds rather involved ...

Relevant scripting hints

- [How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)
- [SystemEvents.SessionEnded Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionended?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)
- [SystemEvents.SessionEnding Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)
- [How to detect Windows shutdown or logoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799955/how-to-detect-windows-shutdown-or-logoff)

Comment: Are you asking the wrong question? Shouldn't it rather be "How do I stop Windows from arbitrarily rebooting my machine, no matter what I am doing on it?"

Comment: No, from what I have read around, that's an anti-pattern, indicated by the fact that Windows won't let you indefinitely post-pone updates in an easy manner. And I can live with the reboots, as long as I get to snapshot the VM. And I'm not really interested in debating the merits of this position - only how to live with it :-)

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://superuser.com/questions/1438892/suspend-or-snapshot-vmware-on-detecting-system-reboot#comment2172395_1438892?

Comment: @jamesdlin True, I forgot I had posted that one. I'll delete the other one, given that it has no answers anyway, and that it's less expanded with regards to details.

Comment: I double posted to the VMWare forum and got directed to this treasure trove of a thread from 2017. It seems to have what I want, but I need to wait for next week before testing it out. https://communities.vmware.com/thread/570079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of back and forth I cobbled together a [solution and put it up on GitHub](https://github.com/fatso83/vmware-auto-suspend). The installation is semi-automated: download two files and right-click an xml file.

The list of Windows events (seen from the Windows Event log) the script responds to are these:

```
Log:System
Source:User32
Event ID:1074
```

```
Log:  Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon/Operational
Source:Winlogon
Event ID:7002
```

```
Log:  Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog-ForwardingPlugin/Operational
Source:Eventlog-ForwardingPlugin
Event ID:6005
```

```
Log:  Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog-ForwardingPlugin/Operational
Source:Eventlog-ForwardingPlugin
Event ID:6006
```

```
Log:Security
Source:Microsoft Windows security auditing.
Event ID:4647
```

and the script looks like this (as of September 2019):

```
@echo off
echo SuspendRunningVMs Command (x64)...
echo Ideas for improving this? Visit https://github.com/fatso83/vmware-auto-suspend

SETLOCAL
REM Specify where vmrun.exe can be located
SET WSPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation"

REM Get the list of currently running VMs
%WSPath%\vmrun.exe list | FIND /V "Total running VMs:" > %temp%\vmlist.txt

REM Suspend all running VMs
FOR /F "delims=*" %%v IN (%temp%\vmlist.txt) DO CALL :SuspendVM "%%v"

:WaitLoop
echo Waiting for the VMs to suspend...
REM Pause until no more VMs are running
%WSPath%\vmrun.exe list | FIND "Total running VMs: 0"
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO End
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
GOTO WaitLoop
 
:End
echo End of script; all VMs suspended.
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF
 
REM Suspend a VM
:SuspendVM
REM Suspend any running VM.  Workaround a "vmrun list" quirk that outputs
REM a blank line, by not trying to suspend a blank VM
IF %1x==x GOTO :EOF
echo Suspending VM %1
%WSPath%\vmrun.exe suspend %1
REM Allow some time after suspend call (allow disk to write vmem).
echo Wait a little bit for the VM to commit...
timeout /t 15 /nobreak
GOTO :EOF
 
REM Resume a VM (not used now, but may have use in future)
:ResumeVM
REM Resume any suspended VM.  Workaround a "vmrun list" quirk that outputs
REM a blank line, by not trying to start a blank VM
IF %1x==x GOTO :EOF
echo Starting VM %1
%WSPath%\vmrun.exe start %1
GOTO :EOF
 
:EOF
```

**Edit:**
I removed the following event as it caused [some](https://github.com/fatso83/vmware-auto-suspend/issues/1) [issues](https://github.com/fatso83/vmware-auto-suspend/issues/2):

```
Log:Security
Source:Microsoft Windows security auditing.
Event ID:4634
```